Determine all possible values for the third term of $S$.

$S$ is a sequence with the following properties,

The first term of $S$ is positive.
The first 3 terms of $S$ form an arithmetic sequence.
If a square is constructed with area equal to a term in $S$, then the perimeter of
that square is the next term in $S$.


(Source: Canadian Open Mathematics Challenge 2015, Question B3)
I was able to find 1 out of the 2 solutions, afterwards I looked at the official solution here, but I found this working to be rather unmotivated (why let the first term be $a^4$?). Here is my work,
For some $a, k \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $a \neq 0$
$S = a, \ a+k, \ a+2k, \ \ldots$
From condition 3 we have,
$4 \sqrt{a} = a+k$
$4 \sqrt{a+k} = a+2k$
Setting $u := \sqrt{a}$ and $v := \sqrt{a+k}$ yields,
$u^2 - 4u + k = 0$
$v^2 - 4v + k = 0$
Since these quadratics are the same we find that $u = v$ so
$\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{a+k}$ and hence $k=0$.
Finally applying the quadratic formula shows us that $u = v = 0, 4$ that is $a = 0, 16$, however since $a \neq 0$ we must have $a = 16$.
I am missing the solution $8 \sqrt{5} - 8$, what have I missed to not get $8 \sqrt{5} - 8$?

To properly solve the system of quadratics, take the difference of the two equations to conclude that
$$ ( u-v) (u+v - 4 ) = 0 . $$
Case 1:  $u-v = 0 $.
OP shows that the only solution is $(a, k) = (16, 0)$.
Note that we rejected $(0, 0)$.
Case 2: $u+v - 4 = 0 $
So $ u + \sqrt{a+k} = 4, a - 4 u +k = 0 $
So $ \sqrt{a+k}  = 4 - u = \sqrt{4u} $, which has solution $ u = 6 - 2 \sqrt{5}$.
Note that we rejected the negative solution as we have to take square roots.
This gives $a = u^2 = 56 - 24 \sqrt{5}, k = 16\sqrt{5} - 32$.
Thus, the third term is $ a + 2k = 8 \sqrt{5} - 8$.
Thus, we have 2 solutions. Including the 2 rejected solutions, this leads to the 4 solutions that Parcly referenced.

You cannot conclude $u=v$ is the only solution of the system of two quadratics. $u=v$ is a solution, but not the only one; Bézout's theorem says that there will be four solutions over $\mathbb C$.
The choice of $a^4$ for the first term in the official solution is simply to make the second and third terms also nice monomials, leading to one quartic which is much easier to solve (by hand and by computer) than two quadratics.

Why must there be 4 solutions, could you elaborate?

@nathan $2×2$, simple as that (Bézout's theorem calls for multiplying the degrees of the equations with respect to the variables of interest, $u,v$).

How would I find the other 3 solutions?
